# How to get value of echo used radio button to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I wanted to get value from table.how can i get value from table.

I have code for table data select radio button

```
echo "<tr><td><input type='radio'  name='select' id= 'delete' value='$deletedvalue' /></td><td>$onetwo[0]</td><td>$onetwo[1]</td></tr>";
```

I have code to get value in js

```
function Deletee(){
        if (document.getElementById('delete').checked) {
                val = document.getElementById('delete').value;
        if (val == null){
                alert("no record delete");
        }
        }
}
```

Comment: Do you have multiple `radio` buttons with the same ID?

Comment: You need to add more substance to your question and explain what the problem is because it is unclear what you are having problems with

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius No i have only one table.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius i wanted to know whether any data from the selecgted or not.

Comment: Sorry - I'm not sure I understand! How does the `deletee` function get called?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsiuswhen i clicked on delete it will call i will update my question with my code